# Implementing a Skip List, syntax error : missing ')' before ';'

Tags: c++

I'm having this problem, where I get weird syntax errors in my skip list implementation and seriously have no clue what could cause this.

This is the code:

skipnode.h:

```
template <typename T>
class SkipNode
{
public:
    T data;
    SkipNode<T> **next;
    SkipNode(T d, int level);
    ~SkipNode();
};
```

skipnode.cpp

```
#include "skipnode.h"
template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::SkipNode(T d, int level)
{
    data = d;
    next = new SkipNode<T>*[level];

    for (int i = 0; i <= level; i++)
        next[i] = 0;
}

template<typename T>
SkipNode<T>::~SkipNode()
{
    delete [] next;
}
```

Skiplist.h

```
#include "skipnode.cpp"
#define MAXLEVEL 4;
template<typename T>
class SkipList
{
public:
    SkipList();
    ~SkipList();
    int randLvl(int max);
    T search(T);
    void insert(T);
private:
    SkipNode<T> *root; 
};
```

Skiplist.cpp

```
#include "skiplist.h"
template<typename T>
SkipList<T>::SkipList()
{
    root = new SkipNode<T>(0,MAXLEVEL);
}
```

When I declare root in Skiplist() I get the following error:

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ';'
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Fixed code, so show includes

Comment: Compilers usually indicate a line number when they report an error of this sort...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is here:

```
#define MAXLEVEL 4;
```

The semicolon is present in the macro expansion, so after the preprocessor pass you end up with:

```
root = new SkipNode<T>(0, 4;);
```

Which is a syntax error (extra semicolon before the closing parenthesis).

To fix it, omit the semicolon in your macro definition:

```
#define MAXLEVEL 4
```

Comment: Thanks alot! If I post my whole code, could you maybe help me with this problem?
[Link](http://i.imgur.com/EiP8ewN)

Comment: @Thisen, that problem is heap corruption, most probably triggered by a buffer overflow. You should ask another question about it, but be sure to investigate with a debugger beforehand.

Comment: I can only post every 90 mins, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `skipnode.h`, or at least declare

```
template <typename T> class SkipNode;
```

before you can use the name `SkipNode` in the definition of `SkipList`.

You'll also (almost certainly) need to define the template member functions in your headers, not source files, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021).

You also have a problem with

```
#define MAXLEVEL 4;
```

which will expand to `4;`, inserting a rogue `;` in the middle of an expression. Use a less broken macro

```
#define MAXLEVEL 4
```

or, better still, a language-level constant

```
const int max_level = 4;
```

Comment: I'm including "skipnode.cpp" in "skiplist.h". Should that not work?

Comment: @Thisen: Yes, although that's rather a confusing way to organise the code, since `.cpp` is usually taken to mean a compilable source file, not a header fragment. I'm not sure what the problem is now you've changed the question. Perhaps you could tell us which line of code causes the error.